# Unnest Array to table Postgres

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

How to unnest ARRAY to table format in Postgres
These are the types that I have created

```
create type ngfcst.test1 as (territory character varying, territoryname character varying, parentname character varying, parentterritory character varying, lowest_level_flag character varying, count bigint);
```

I am doing an array_agg to return a resultset using this type. Below is a sample output from function test12:

```
select * from test12(
    'some_parameters');
OUTPUT (2 records):
{"(\"rec11",rec12,\"rec13",\"rec14\",rec15,1)","(\"rec21\",rec22,\"rec23\",\"rec24\",rec25,2)"}
```

i want the data in proper table format but doing this doesnt help :

```
with main as(
    select * from  test12(
    'some_parameters'))
    select unnest(o_show_proxy::ngfcst.test1[]) as unnest_col from main;
```

this does separate the records, but not the columns.
I want the output in rows and column format as we get from below query :

```
select * from unnest(array[row('row11','row12','row13','row14','row15',1),
              row('row21','row22','row23','row24','row25',2)]::ngfcst.test1[])
```

Let me know if there is any way to get the output in rows and column format.

Comment: Your sample output is inconsistent. Please check once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `cross join lateral` will help --

Based on your example. considering your function `test12()` is returning proper array formation according to your user defined TYPE `test1`.

Try this:

```
with cte as(
    select * from  test12(
    'some_parameters')
)
    select t.* from cte cross join lateral unnest(cte.o_show_proxy::test1[]) t;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2d86a3b6f73dd676afa75aeecf8b18cc)

Comment: Hi Akhilesh, I have been reading up on the cross join lateral functionality and where to use it, but I am not able to understand how it works. Can you please help here

Comment: Please read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28557803/7772483)